# Queues dequeue enqueue error for input stream

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I am trying to work with data structure of queue which is kind of circular queue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum boolean{
   false,true
};

struct ArrayQueue{
    int rare,front;
    int capacity;
    int *array;
};

struct ArrayQueue* CreateQueue(int cap)
{
    struct ArrayQueue* queue;
    queue = (struct ArrayQueue*)malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayQueue));
    queue->rare = -1;
    queue->front = -1;
    queue->capacity = cap;
    queue->array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*queue->capacity);
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<queue->capacity;i++)
        queue->array[i] = 0;
    return(queue);
}

enum boolean isFull(struct ArrayQueue *queue)
{
    return((queue->rare+1)%queue->capacity == queue->front);
}

enum boolean isEmpty(struct ArrayQueue *queue)
{
    return(queue->front == -1);
}

int ElementsInQueue(struct ArrayQueue *queue)
{
    return(((queue->capacity-queue->front)+queue->rare+1)%queue->capacity);
}

void En_queue(struct ArrayQueue *queue,int item)
{
    if (isFull(queue) == false)
    {
        queue->rare = (queue->rare+1)%queue->capacity;
        queue->array[queue->rare] = item;
        if (queue->front == -1)
            queue->front = queue->rare;
    }
}

int De_queue(struct ArrayQueue *queue)
{
    int data;
    if (isEmpty(queue) == false)
    {
        data = queue->array[queue->front];
        queue->array[queue->front] = 0;
        if (queue->front == queue->rare)
        {
            queue->front = -1;
            queue->rare = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            queue->front = queue->front+1%queue->capacity;
        }
        return data;
    }
}

void Display(struct ArrayQueue *queue)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n Displaying the queue : \n");
    for (i=0;i<queue->capacity;i++)
        printf("%d ",queue->array[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int cap,choice,item;
    struct ArrayQueue *queue;
    printf("\nEnter the Capacity of Queue: ");
    scanf("%d",&cap);
    queue = CreateQueue(cap);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("\n1.Enqueue");
        printf("\n2.Dequeue");
        printf("\n3.Display");
        printf("\n4.Exit");
        printf("\nEnter choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1: if (isFull(queue) == true)
                {
                    printf("\nQueue is Full..");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                   printf("\nEnter a number: ");
                   scanf("%d",&item);
                   En_queue(queue,item);
                   Display(queue);
                }
                break;
        case 2: if (isEmpty(queue)== true)
                {
                    printf("\nQueue is Empty..");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    item = De_queue(queue);
                    printf("\nItem popped is: %d",item);
                    Display(queue);
                }
                break;
        case 3: Display(queue);
                break;
        case 4: exit(0);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

It looks perfect in first glance but it is having few problems.

See the screenshots

#### after insertion

2nd. Deleting and inserting simultaneously
[image]

3rd. the problem occurred
[image]

My input stream was (according to this pattern)...

1. Enqueue
2. Dequeue
3. Display
4. Exit

```
{1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1}

                        |___|
                      here is the problem
```

- When I entered 2 for dequeuing the queue was full, but nothing got deleted. Output was some garbage value
- Then I entered 1 for enqueuing the queue was full but it did not showed the queue is full; Instead it asked me to enter a number.

(as I have dequeued first so i thought to enqueue an element first and then to enter the choice as 1. but again it asked me to enter a number.)

I couldn't figure out the mistakes. forgive me for my explanation and weird vocabulary. Can you please try the code and give the input stream to figure out the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `queue->front = queue->front+1%queue->capacity;`, did you mean to put parentheses around `queue->front+1`?

Comment: To make it easier to test, change your `display()` function to iterate from `head` to `rear` and not from `0` to `capacity`.

Comment: meowgoesthedog  thank you. it worked. :)

Comment: SHG as it is a circular queue sometimes head will be greater than rear. and i was unable to come up with an idea just to show the elements and not whole queue and thus i placed 0 to suggest the place is empty. thanks for your suggestion. :)

Comment: I improved your formatting a little bit, but it's difficult to say what you meant about where the problem lies. I would suggest that you indent the {1,1,1...} line 4 spaces so that the "here is the problem" bracket shows where the problem really lies.

Comment: If you "really suck at explaining things," we're going to have a difficult time understanding you, and the answers you get aren't going to be very good. I suggest you get better at explaining things.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: If that solves the problem, I would suggest you post it as an answer. That way it can be upvoted and marked correct.

Comment: @JimMischel I feel like an answer to fix a simple typo wouldn't be very educational; perhaps it should be flagged as "... being caused by a typo" instead

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: I voted to close as "... being caused by a typo"

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct answer.  thanks to everyone :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum boolean{
   false,true
};

struct ArrayQueue{
    int rare,front;
    int capacity;
    int *array;
};

struct ArrayQueue* CreateQueue(int cap)
{
    struct ArrayQueue* queue;
    queue = (struct ArrayQueue*)malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayQueue));
    queue->rare = -1;
    queue->front = -1;
    queue->capacity = cap;
    queue->array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*queue->capacity);
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<queue->capacity;i++)
        queue->array[i] = 0;
    return(queue);
}

enum boolean isFull(struct ArrayQueue *queue)
{
    return((queue->rare+1)%queue->capacity == queue->front);
}

enum boolean isEmpty(struct ArrayQueue *queue)
{
    return(queue->front == -1);
}

int ElementsInQueue(struct ArrayQueue *queue)
{
    return(((queue->capacity-queue->front)+queue->rare+1)%queue->capacity);
}

void En_queue(struct ArrayQueue *queue,int item)
{
    if (isFull(queue) == false)
    {
        queue->rare = (queue->rare+1)%queue->capacity;
        queue->array[queue->rare] = item;
        if (queue->front == -1)
            queue->front = queue->rare;
    }
}

int De_queue(struct ArrayQueue *queue)
{
    int data;
    if (isEmpty(queue) == false)
    {
        data = queue->array[queue->front];
        queue->array[queue->front] = 0;
        if (queue->front == queue->rare)
        {
            queue->front = -1;
            queue->rare = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            queue->front = (queue->front+1)%queue->capacity;
        }
        return data;
    }
}

void Display(struct ArrayQueue *queue)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n Displaying the queue : \n");
    for (i=0;i<queue->capacity;i++)
        printf("%d ",queue->array[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int cap,choice,item;
    struct ArrayQueue *queue;
    printf("\nEnter the Capacity of Queue: ");
    scanf("%d",&cap);
    queue = CreateQueue(cap);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("\n1.Enqueue");
        printf("\n2.Dequeue");
        printf("\n3.Display");
        printf("\n4.Exit");
        printf("\nEnter choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1: if (isFull(queue) == true)
                {
                    printf("\nQueue is Full..");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                   printf("\nEnter a number: ");
                   scanf("%d",&item);
                   En_queue(queue,item);
                   Display(queue);
                }
                break;
        case 2: if (isEmpty(queue)== true)
                {
                    printf("\nQueue is Empty..");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    item = De_queue(queue);
                    printf("\nItem popped is: %d",item);
                    Display(queue);
                }
                break;
        case 3: Display(queue);
                break;
        case 4: exit(0);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```